# Netbeans 7.2 error reported on start

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7

When I start Netbeans it is showing following message:

> Warning - could not install some modules: Editor Macros - 
>   The module Editor Library was requested in implementation version "19" but only "20" was 
>   found. IDE Platform - The module named org.netbeans.modules.editor.macros/0-1 was needed 
>   and not found. Spring Web MVC - The module named org.netbeans.modules.spring.beans/0-1 was 
>   needed and not found. 22 further modules could not be installed due to the above problems.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Did you tried updating the software?

Answer (score 1):

Some aspects:

- delete or rename your netbeans user dirs (see [here](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWhatIsUserdir) for their location). This will make NB like it was after installation.
- Do you have the current version of spring plugin?
- Did you import any plugins from previous NB intsallations?
- If you are running on Vista, make shure *User Account Control* if off while installation / update through update center (see [here](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqInstallPluginVista))
- [Bug 218373 (fixed)](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=218373)

Answer (score 0):

Even I had this problem while installing gwt4nb module. Simply uninstall netbeans 7.2 and install Netbeans 7.3. The problem will be solved!!!